# Filter table using jQuery by column instead of row

Tags: php, jquery, html

Table goes like this. And my goal is to only show the area that is equals to what is inputted in the search box.

```
|Stage|Area|Part|
|  A  | 1  | 1  |
|  A  | 1  | 2  |
|  A  | 1  | 3  |
|  A  | 2  | 1  |
|  A  | 2  | 2  |
|  A  | 2  | 3  |
|  A  | 3  | 1  |
|  A  | 3  | 2  |
|  A  | 3  | 3  |
```

I'm currently following this [code](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2011/01/03/searching-text-in-a-html-table-using-jquery/). There's also a demo on that site. But if type in 3 in the search box it goes like this:

```
|Stage|Area|Part|
|  A  | 1  | 3  |
|  A  | 2  | 3  |
|  A  | 3  | 1  |
|  A  | 3  | 2  |
|  A  | 3  | 3  |
```

I don't know how to make the jQuery search by column and give the result below:

```
|Stage|Area|Part|
|  A  | 3  | 1  |
|  A  | 3  | 2  |
|  A  | 3  | 3  |
```

I'm an amateur in jquery so please bear with me.

Table markup:

```
<input type="text" id="search"/>

<table width="100%" id="tblData">
    <!-- Cells here -->
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#search').keyup(function()
    {
        searchTable($(this).val());
    });
});

function searchTable(inputVal)
{
    var table = $('#tblData');
    table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
    {
        var allCells = $(row).find('td');
        if(allCells.length > 0)
        {
            var found = false;
            allCells.each(function(index, td)
            {
                var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                {
                    found = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should post your code here.

Comment: I'm just using the code given in the website. No changes.

Comment: You would have to significantly rewrite the jQuery code you linked to. If nobody else replies with code you could try: https://www.datatables.net/ with https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html

Comment: Too bad. It's not what I'm looking for. I only the jquery to search a column but display the whole row if found. I only want what is inputted in the search box to be displayed. http://i.share.pho.to/d2552f82_o.png

Comment: Oh man, so glad I don't have to deal with stuff like this anymore now that I'm using Backbone and Marionette js. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something like this a while back that should do what you need:

http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/vnxdt

The example above is set to search on the first two columns of the table. This is done by passing an array of column numbers as a parameter i.e column 1 would be 1:

```
initLiveFilter(element, [1,2]);
```

If you type "*hitch*" into the search field for example, it will return all hitch hikers books. If you type "*book*" it will match all rows that are either book or audio book.

## Your Example

---

The snippet below more closely matches your example (with a few extra rows for dramatic effect). Here you can search on the second column (area) only.

To make this work for you, just pass the table element and the columns you want to index through to the `initLiveFilter(liveFilter, columnsToIndex);` function call.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

var columnsToIndex = [2], // first column is 1
 liveFilter = jQuery("#liveFilter");

initLiveFilter(liveFilter, columnsToIndex);
});

// Live Filter
function initLiveFilter(liveFilter, columnsToIndex) {

if (typeof liveFilter !== "undefined" && liveFilter.length > 0) {
 
 liveFilter.wrap('<div class="liveFilter"></div>').parent().prepend('<div class="liveFilterContainer"><div class="group"><input type="text" class="liveFilterInput" value="" placeholder="Filter by Area" /><a href="#" class="clearField" title="Clear Filter">x</a></div></div><div class="noResults"><strong>Sorry.</strong> There is no match for your filter; please try again.</div>');
 
 var thisObj = this,
  liveFilterWrapper = liveFilter.parent(),
  liveFilterField = liveFilterWrapper.find("input.liveFilterInput"),
  liveFilterGrid = jQuery("#liveFilter"),
  liveFilterGridRows = liveFilterGrid.find("tr:gt(0)"), // gt(0) prevents the first row (normally a TH) from being included.
  liveFilterClear = liveFilterWrapper.find(".clearField"),
  liveFilterNoResults = liveFilterGrid.prev(),
  liveFilterDataArray = [],
 
  //Create an array and populate it with key codes that should not cause shake effects

  characterValidationArray = [8,45,46], //backspace, insert, delete
 
  //Create an array and populate it with key codes that don't trigger an action
 
  characterExclusionArray = [13,20,27,33,34,37,39,35,36,16,17,18,144,145]; // enter, caps, esc, page up, page down, left, right, home, end, shift, ctrl, alt, num lock, scroll lock

 thisObj.init = function(){
  
  if (typeof columnsToIndex !== "undefined" && columnsToIndex.length > 0) {
   
   for (col=0; col<=columnsToIndex.length-1; col++)
   {   
    liveFilterGridRows.children("td:nth-child(" + columnsToIndex[col] + ")").each(function(i){
    
     liveFilterDataArray[liveFilterDataArray.length++] = jQuery(this).text();
    
    });
   }
   
  } else {
   
   liveFilterGridRows.children("td:first-child").each(function(i){
    
    liveFilterDataArray[i] = jQuery(this).text();
    
   });
  }
 
  liveFilterField.on("keyup",function(key){
   
   thisObj.filterRows(key);
   
  });
  
  liveFilterClear.on("click",function(){
 
   thisObj.clearField();
   
   return false;  
  });   
 };
 
 thisObj.clearField = function() {
 
  liveFilterField.val('');
  liveFilterClear.fadeOut(300);
  liveFilterNoResults.slideUp(300);
  liveFilterGridRows.show();
  liveFilterGrid.show();   
 };
 
 thisObj.filterRows = function(key) {
 
  if (jQuery.inArray(key.keyCode,characterExclusionArray) === -1) {
  
   var liveFilterValue = liveFilterField.val();

   if (liveFilterValue !== "") {

    liveFilterClear.fadeIn(300);

    rowsToShow = [];
    
    var currentRow = 0;
    
   // Check the value entered against a regular expression matched with the column data. If a match exists add the row to a new array

    for (var i=0; i < liveFilterDataArray.length; i+=1) {

     RE = eval("/" + liveFilterValue + "/i");
 
     if (liveFilterDataArray[i].match(RE)) {
      
      rowsToShow.push(currentRow);
      
     }
     
     if(currentRow < liveFilterGridRows.length - 1) {

      currentRow++;
      
     } else {

      currentRow = 0;

     }
    }
   
   // If there are matches, show the grid, hide all the rows and show the selected ones

    if (rowsToShow.length > 0) {

     liveFilterGrid.show();
     liveFilterGridRows.hide();
     
     if (liveFilterNoResults.is(":visible")) {
      liveFilterNoResults.slideUp(150);
     }
     
     for (var i=0; i < rowsToShow.length; i+=1) {

      jQuery(liveFilterGridRows.get(rowsToShow[i])).show();

     }
     
   // If there are NO matches we hide the grid and display an error panel. If an incorrect value is entered while the error panel is visible it shakes itself assuming if it doesn't match any of the excluded values defined in the characterValidationArray
     
    } else {
     
     liveFilterGrid.hide();

     // if the no results panel is shown and the effects queue length is 0 and there are no illegal character presses
           
     if (liveFilterNoResults.is(":visible") && liveFilterNoResults.queue().length === 0 && jQuery.inArray(key.keyCode,characterValidationArray) == -1) {
      
      liveFilterNoResults.effect('shake', {times:3, distance:3}, 100);

     } else {
      liveFilterNoResults.slideDown(150); 
     }
    }
    
   // If the value entered is blank, hide the clear field button, show the grid and all of its rows and hide the no results panel if it is visible
   
   } else {

    thisObj.clearField();
   }
  }  
 };
 
 thisObj.init();
}
}
```

```css
.liveFilter {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterContainer {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 6px;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterContainer .group {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterContainer .liveFilterInput {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 padding: 4px 30px 4px 4px;
 color: #666;
 margin: 0;
 outline: 0;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterContainer .liveFilterInput.default {
 color: #ccc;
 font-style: italic;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterContainer .clearField {
 background: #80bce8;
 width: 18px;
 padding: 0 6px 3px 6px;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 right: -29px;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterList {
 width: 400px;
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 border-top: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterList tr th:first-child,
.liveFilter .liveFilterList tr td:first-child {
 padding-left: 5px; 
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterList tr th {
 text-align: left;
 padding: 3px 0;
}
.liveFilter .liveFilterList tr td {
 border-top: solid 1px #eee;
 padding: 3px 0;
 color: #333;
}
.liveFilter .noResults {
 display: none;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 background: #982929;
}


/* For aesthetics only */
    
body {
 margin: 10px;
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="liveFilter" class="liveFilterList" border="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th>Stage</th>
  <th>Area</th>
  <th>Part</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>5</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but I don't know how to revise it to make it work for a searchbox that is not displayed using jquery

Comment: @iamDevlin Here is an older version I created that does not dynamically create the markup around the table. You just need to alter the selectors so that it points to the elements you want to use.
http://www.chris-spittles.co.uk/codeForForums/526/demo.html